# Knockout.js - Reload a dropdown with new options using the value of another drop down

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, drop-down-menu, viewmodel, cascadingdropdown

I've seen similar things, where people have wanted to do this in ASP .NET, generic JavaScript, PHP, etc., but now here we have KnockOut that throws a wrench in things, since its fields are already rendered dynamically.  Now here I go wanting to rewrite a dropdown when another is changed... dynamic loading on top of dynamic loading, all in old-fashioned cascading style....

I have a dropdown, "ourTypes", I've called it, that when changed, should re-write the options of the "slots" dropdown to its left.  I have a `.subscribe()` function that creates new options based on a limit I get from the "ourTypes" value.  All well and good, but how do we make the dropdown actually reflect those new values?

**HTML:**

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.slots, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', value: $data.SlotPosition"></select> 
<select data-bind="options: $root.ourTypes, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', value: $data.OurTypeId"></select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var slots = [
    { Text: "1", Value: "1" },
    { Text: "2", Value: "2" },
    { Text: "3", Value: "3" }
];
var ourTypes = [
    { ID:"1", Name:"None", Limit:0 },
    { ID:"2", Name:"Fruits", Limit:5 },
    { ID:"3", Name:"Vegetables", Limit:5 },
    { ID:"4", Name:"Meats", Limit:2 }
];
var dataList = [        
    { SlotPosition: "1", OurTypeId: 4 },
    { SlotPosition: "2", OurTypeId: 2 },
    { SlotPosition: "3", OurTypeId: 3 }
];

var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(dataList);
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

function MyViewModel(dataList) {
    var self = this;
    self.slots = slots;
    self.ourTypes = ourTypes;
    self.OurTypeId = ko.observable(dataList.OurTypeId);
    self.SlotPosition = ko.observable(dataList.SlotPosition);

    self.OurTypeId.subscribe(function() {
        if (!ko.isObservable(self.SlotPosition))
            self.SlotPosition = ko.observable("1");

        // Get our new limit based on value
        var limit = ko.utils.arrayFirst(ourTypes, function(type) {
            return type.ID == self.OurTypeId();
        }).Limit;  

        // Build options here
        self.slots.length = 0;
        self.slots.push({Text:"",Value:""});
        for (var i=1; i < limit+1; i++) {
            self.slots.push({Text:i, Value:i});
        }

        // What else do I do here to make the dropdown refresh
        // with the new values?
    });
}
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/Lspwc4n4/

Comment: something like this you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/Lspwc4n4/3/ . cheers

Comment: You made the `self.slots` equal to an `observableArray(slots)` and added `self.slots([])` to clear it before the pushing started.  Awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: Downvoter to the question, care to explain?  I thought I laid out that this was a cascading drop-down problem using KO as well as I could have.  Included the code and the Fiddle.  Instead of just randomly downvoting, ought to explain why and what could've been done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just made small changes in you code

**View Model:**

```
        self.slots = ko.observableArray(slots); //should make it observable
        self.ourTypes = ko.observableArray(ourTypes);
        self.OurTypeId = ko.observable(dataList[0].OurTypeId); // initial value setting 
        self.SlotPosition = ko.observable(dataList.SlotPosition);
       //Inside subscribe 
        self.slots([]);  // clearing before filling new values
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/Lspwc4n4/3/)**

Comment: And I still can't believe how close I was.... making those arrays observable was 99% of what I needed to do...